# Python randomnumber array

Tags: python, arrays, random, numbers, position

So, i have a small issue witch creating random numbers for an 2d array in python.

I have a matrix looking like this

```
matrix:
       row = ['.' for i in range(w)]
        self.matrix = [row]
        for j in range(h - 1):
            row = ['.' for i in range(w)]
            self.matrix.append(row)

w = int(input("please insert the width of the array: "))
h = int(input("please insert the height of the array: "))

user = int(input("please insert a number for objects: "))

x = random.sample(range(w), user)
y = random.sample(range(h), user)

list(zip(x, y))
```

So, now i want to create so many random numbers as user input. For example, it the user inputs 100, i need 100 numbers from x and y, so that i can use them as position, to insert objects randomly into the array.

But if the width and height are smaller then userinput i get an error.

Comment: This here "in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")"

Comment: Your `user` value is greater than `len(range(w))` (or `len(range(h))`)

Comment: Yeah, but is there a way to overcome this, i have tried with other random possibilities, but haven't come to a solution.

Comment: Calling `random.sample` twice independently doesn't make a lot of sense to me. That means that all of the points you choose from the grid will have completely unique x coordinates and y coordinates - for example, you'll never end up with both (0,0) and (0,1). If you want actually random coords, you need to create a single list of all coordinates and call `sample` on that list just once.

Comment: That does make more sense, i will try it out. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the following two lines for `x` and `y`should give you the results you expect:

```
x = [random.randint(0, w-1) for c in range(user)]
y = [random.randint(0, h-1) for c in range(user)]
```

Comment: yes, that did work, thanks so much, it helps me alot!